# Spark Accumulator confusion

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm writing a Spark job that takes in data from multiple sources, filters bad input rows, and outputs a slightly modified version of the input.  The job has two additional requirements:

- I must keep track of the number of bad inputs rows per source to notify those upstream providers.
- I must support an output limit per source.

The job seemed straightforward and I approached the problem using accumulators to keep track of the number of filtered rows per source.  However, when I implemented the final `.limit(N)`, my accumulator behavior changed.  Here's some striped down sample code that triggers the behavior on a single source:

```
from pyspark.sql import Row, SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from random import randint

def filter_and_transform_parts(rows, filter_int, accum):
    for r in rows:
        if r[0] == filter_int:
            accum.add(1)
            continue

        yield r[0], r[1] + 1, r[2] + 1

def main():
    spark= SparkSession \
           .builder \
           .appName("Test") \
           .getOrCreate()

    sc = spark.sparkContext
    accum = sc.accumulator(0)

    # 20 inputs w/ tuple having 4 as first element                                                                                                                                                                                        
    inputs = [(4, randint(1, 10), randint(1, 10)) if x % 5 == 0 else (randint(6, 10), randint(6, 10), randint(6, 10)) for x in xrange(100)]

    rdd = sc.parallelize(inputs)
    # filter out tuples where 4 is first element                                                                                                                                                                                          
    rdd = rdd.mapPartitions(lambda r: filter_and_transform_parts(r, 4, accum))


    # if not limit, accumulator value is 20                                                                                                                                                                                               
    # if limit and limit_count <= 63, accumulator value is 0                                                                                                                                                                              
    # if limit and limit_count >= 64, accumulator value is 20                                                                                                                                                                               
    limit = True
    limit_count = 63

    if limit:
        rdd = rdd.map(lambda r: Row(r[0], r[1], r[2]))
        df_schema = StructType([StructField("val1", IntegerType(), False),
                                StructField("val2", IntegerType(), False),
                                StructField("val3", IntegerType(), False)])
        df = spark.createDataFrame(rdd, schema=df_schema)
        df = df.limit(limit_count)
        df.write.mode("overwrite").csv('foo/')
    else:
        rdd.saveAsTextFile('foo/')

    print "Accum value: {}".format(accum.value)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

The problem is that my accumulator sometimes reports the number of filtered rows and sometimes doesn't, depending on the limit specified and number of inputs for a source.  However, in all situations the filtered rows don't make it into the output meaning the filter occurred and the accumulator should have a value.

If you can shed some light on this that'd be very helpful, thanks!

**Update**:

- Adding a `rdd.persist()` call after `mapPartitions` made the accumulator behavior consistent.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, it doesnt't matter what the `limit_count`'s value is.

The reason why sometime `Accum value` is 0 is because you performe **accumulator**       in **transformations**(e.g.: rdd.map,rdd.mapPartitions).

Spark only guaranty that accumulator works as well inside **actions**(e.g.: rdd.foreach)

Lets make a little bit of change on your code:

```
from pyspark.sql import *
from random import randint


def filter_and_transform_parts(rows, filter_int, accum):
    for r in rows:
        if r[0] == filter_int:
            accum.add(1)


def main():
    spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("Test").getOrCreate()

    sc = spark.sparkContext
    print(sc.applicationId)
    accum = sc.accumulator(0)

    inputs = [(4, x * 10, x * 100) if x % 5 == 0 else (randint(6, 10), x * 10, x * 100) for x in xrange(100)]
    rdd = sc.parallelize(inputs)
    rdd.foreachPartition(lambda r: filter_and_transform_parts(r, 4, accum))

    limit = True
    limit_count = 10 or 'whatever'

    if limit:
        rdd = rdd.map(lambda r: Row(val1=r[0], val2=r[1], val3=r[2]))
        df = spark.createDataFrame(rdd)
        df = df.limit(limit_count)
        df.write.mode("overwrite").csv('file:///tmp/output')
    else:
        rdd.saveAsTextFile('file:///tmp/output')

    print "Accum value: {}".format(accum.value)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

**Accum value** is equle to 20 all the time

For more information:

> http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.2/programming-guide.html#accumulators

Comment: Thanks for the link to the relevant docs.  I'm still a bit confused though, do you find the following statements true?  saveAsTextFile is an action and was triggering my upstream accumulator to populate properly.  df.write is not an action and makes no guarantees about accumulators (which leads to the situation where it sometimes populates depending on the limit)